# F# Create list of tuples from flat list by taking n and n-1

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, tuples

So basically I have a list [1,2,3,4,...,n] and I want to create a new list (of tuples) and then use List.Map to apply a function to the new list.
The new list would be of the form [(NULL,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),...,(n,n-1)]

But I'm not directly seeing what the best approach would be to solve this problem.
Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
With the answers below I eventually solved my issue like this

```
let TotalDistance (points:ResizeArray<TrackPoint>) = List.ofSeq(points) |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.map(fun (x,y) -> DistanceBetween x.Position y.Position) |> Seq.sum
```

With Trackpoint being a collection of coordinates (C#) and DistanceBetween being the haversine formula.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this looks to easy or I misunderstood the question : 
[1..10] |> List.map (fun n -> (n+1,n) )
for the first item, I'm not sure, there are no nulls in f#

Comment: yes that works too (doh ;) ) ... but you get one `n+1` to much - I guess you could try with `n-1` instead ;)

Comment: @elios264 That would only work for the case where your input list is sequential numbers, but it doesn't solve the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically what `Seq.pairwise` does.

```
[1..4] |> Seq.pairwise
> val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4)]
```

You could pipe it through `map` and swap the tuple items if necessary. `windowed` is a bit overkill for this since it creates an array for each element of the list.

If you really need the first element to appear twice you could cons `None` to the list.

```
let pairs xs = 
    None::xs 
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.toList

pairs (List.map Some [1..4])
```

Comment: very true - forgot `pairwise` ;)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `Seq.windowed` it does almost what you want:

```
[1..10] 
|> Seq.windowed 2 
|> List.ofSeq;;

val it : int [] list =
  [[|1; 2|]; [|2; 3|]; [|3; 4|]; [|4; 5|]; [|5; 6|]; [|6; 7|]; [|7; 8|];
   [|8; 9|]; [|9; 10|]]
```

I will *ignore* your `NULL` (we don't want this really ;)) and play a bit so you get:

```
[1..10] 
|> Seq.windowed 2 
|> Seq.map (fun [|a;b|] -> (b,a)) 
|> List.ofSeq;;

val it : (int * int) list =
  [(2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 3); (5, 4); (6, 5); (7, 6); (8, 7); (9, 8); (10, 9)]
```

So the thing you are searching is:

```
let pairList ls = 
   ls
   |> Seq.windowed 2 
   |> Seq.map (fun [|a;b|] -> (b,a)) 
   |> List.ofSeq
```

See it as an exercise to get your `NULL` in ;)
(ok this is mean - your `(Null,1)` does not fit in the sequence

Comment: I like it but i'm going to go with seq.pairwise.